# Set custom cursor, system wide, for all cursor IDs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++builder

Here is the code I'm using:

```
HCURSOR hCrossHair;
```

...

```
hCrossHair = LoadCursorFromFile( "ColorTool_CrossHair.cur" );
```

...

```
SetSystemCursor( hCrossHair, OCR_NORMAL );
```

Is there a way of setting the cursor so it overrides all others? For example, if I specify `OCR_NORMAL` in `SetSystemCursor` then it only replaces the general arrow (default) cursor, but as soon as the mouse is over a text field somewhere or the edge of a re-sizable window, etc, it changes to the usual cursor for those situations.

I've also tried

```
SetSystemCursor( hCrossHair, OCR_NORMAL );
SetSystemCursor( hCrossHair, OCR_IBEAM );
SetSystemCursor( hCrossHair, OCR_SIZE );
```

but that it appears only one of the calls (usually the first one) will be applied.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648395.aspx):

> It replaces the contents of the system cursor specified by the id parameter with the contents of the cursor specified by the hcur parameter and then destroys hcur.

That means you have to re-load, or make a copy of, the cursor every time you want to call `SetSystemCursor()`.

Also keep in mind that this will only replace *system* cursors, not user-defined cursors that are manually assigned to the VCL's `TScreen::Cursors[]` property after app startup.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the documentation. I am looking for a way to force a custom cursor in all contexts - arrow, ibeam, everything. Am example of where I've seen this before is Microsoft Frontpage 2003's color picker's select-from-anywhere-on-screen that locks the cursor into a dropper.

Comment: You are going about this all wrong then.  Such apps simply use `SetCursor()` and `SetCapture()` for that. While the mouse is captured, other apps do not receive `WM_SETCURSOR` messages to change the cursor. See this article for details: [Using SetCapture() and ReleaseCapture() correctly (usually
during a drag n' drop operation)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127813/). It mentions this very technique is how Spy++ implements its crosshair cursor while moving the mouse over other apps, much like Frontpage's dropper.

Comment: Remy, as always, you are completely correct. Thanks yet again. Signed, an long time C++ Builder user who has listened to your advice since the news://forums.borland.com and BCB4/5 days.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying `SetCapture( Handle ); HOrigCursor = ::SetCursor( HCrossHair );` to set the custom cursor and `if ( HOrigCursor ) ::SetCursor( HOrigCursor ); ReleaseCapture();` to reset it, which seems to work, but only in my programs window. As soon as I move the cursor outside of it it goes back to the normal cursor. I have studied that link but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you checking to make sure that `SetCapture()` succeeds in the first place? Is your specified `Handle` in the foreground at the time of the capture? Only a foreground window can capture the mouse.

Comment: You're right, `SetCapture( Handle );` is returning NULL each time. I'm passing it my main form's `->Handle` but I also tried passing the Handle of several components on my form and got the same result.

Comment: `SetCapture()` returns the `HWND` of the window that was previously capturing the mouse when you took the capture. So NULL would mean no previous capturing window. But you would know if the capture was successful if your app receives mouse messages (`WM_MOUSEMOVE`, etc) while moving the mouse outside of the window you pass to `SetCapture()`.

Comment: I understand that, but alas I still can't seem to get my custom cursor to stay set outside of my program's window. I just changes back to the normal cursor.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear when I said `SetCapture( Handle );`, `Handle` is the main form's Handle property, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tested it, and it worked fine for me - but only when calling `SetCapture()` and `SetCursor()` in response to a mouse down event. As long as the mouse is held down, the cursor does not change while moving it around the screen over other apps. As soon as the mouse is released, or focus moves away from your window, then the capture is automatically released and the cursor resets. Which makes sense, since mouse capture was originally designed for supporting drag&drop operations.

Comment: Ah, that explains it; I hadn't realized that is /had/ to be during a mouse down event. Thank you for clarifying that. I see this is how Spy++ does it, though I'm am curious how FP2003 does it without holding any mouse button down.